# How i wait the return value of a function

Tags: c#

I have a function I use for sending a message to a server. The server returns a string like 'true' or 'false' and the client returns the value returned by the server. My problem is that when I call ClientReturn with my request I get my return in the function but not into another function string or if(ClientReturn() == "false / true") is empty.

```
    public static string ClientReturn(string ip, int port, string message)
    {
        string toReturn = "";
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += delegate (object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            //---data to send to the server---
            string textToSend = message;

            //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(ip, port);
            NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

            //---send the text---
            Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            //---read back the text---
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            toReturn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Returned: " + toReturn); //It's the return of the server
            client.Close();
        };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        return toReturn; //Return the value but not work it's return nothing
    }
```

Comment: Please, let `BackgroundWorker` rest in peace, it's an obsolete conception now. Try `Task` and `async` + `await` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not waiting for the `BackgroundWorker` to complete.

To be honest, `BackgroundWorker` is obsolete anyway. Instead use `async` and `await`.

You are also missing `using` blocks to dispose the client and stream.

```cs
public static async Task<string> ClientReturn(string ip, int port, string textToSend)
{
    //---create a TCPClient object at the IP and port no.---
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())
    {
        await client.ConnectAsync(ip, port);
        using (NetworkStream nwStream = client.GetStream())
        {
            byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textToSend);

            //---send the text---
            Console.WriteLine("Sending : " + textToSend);
            await nwStream.WriteAsync(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            //---read back the text---
            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = await nwStream.ReadAsync(bytesToRead, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
            var toReturn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Returned: " + toReturn); //It's the return of the server
            return toReturn; //Return the value but not work it's return nothing
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to return Task<string> and make the function async?

Comment: Yeah often forget the obvious...